# Django new line in output

Tags: django, newline

I try to print the model object in a new line but my code doesn't work. Here is my code and I want to know how can I fix this problem?

```
def list_create_tasks(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        all_tasks=Task.objects.all()
        return HttpResponse('\n'.join(map(str, all_tasks)))
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML does not care about a new line. In order to write on a new line, you use the [**`<br>`** tag [w3schools]](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp):

```
def list_create_tasks(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        all_tasks=Task.objects.all()
        return HttpResponse('<br>'.join(map(str, all_tasks)))
```